# Dead oceans, robot factory farms and freighters, personal anti-gravity transportation devices

Tags: story-identification, artificial-gravity

This is one I came across in a different forum that has gone unanswered for a long time. Anyone here have any ideas? Information from original post follows:

> There was a sci-fi novel of standard length that dealt with a somewhat
>   dystopic future. There might have been as I remember farm fields (in
>   the UK?) where they tried to eliminate the birds from the hedgerows in
>   order to increase crop yields.
>
> The hero escaped from a factory farm, and somehow gets on a robot
>   freighter headed to sea, probably down the West African coast. There
>   is a description of the desolation of this future time, such as the
>   atomic powered ship that could keep going regardless, but for what
>   purpose? The seas were dead, but traveled by robot or lightly crewed
>   freighters.
>
> He arrives somehow in an area where the very old and rich have found a
>   haven of compounds. Finally, I can remember a scene on the coast of
>   Africa (the continent sure, but perhaps along a desolate sandy coast)
>   where an individual of advanced age was found dead (murdered)
>   drifting along the beach strapped to a refrigerator sized
>   anti-gravity unit.

Also:

> Set on Earth, probably in the 21st century (a long time in the future
>   for its publ date of 60s), and in a setting where things have gone
>   down the tubes environmentally due to the usual cast of "characters".
>   The English agribusiness, contrary to even 60s UK farm fields, spanned
>   miles and miles, like fields in Kansas or something.
>
> And the protagonist saw the hedgerows made for wind control with
>   fences or nets very high. But birds still survived their planned
>   extermination and hid out in the hedgerows/nets. Due to some intrigue,
>   he has to flee England, and my next recollection is the guy on one of
>   these ocean-going robot ships (robot or staffed by a very few
>   crewmembers) heading away from England on desolate seas.
>
> I remember that the seas were almost lifeless and empty. At some
>   point, he arrives in West Africa, where there are still villas and
>   development for the very rich. These people are so rich that they have
>   every possible aid and assistance to continue to survive and make
>   money, including refrigerator sized anti-grav units that allow them to
>   scud slightly above the ground in their comings and goings. There was
>   some kind of an affair, or dinner party, in one of these villas as the
>   protagonist was trying to find out something about his enemies or his
>   predicament.
>
> It may seem that the world population had crashed, for a number of
>   reasons, so that there were automated production facilities, but no
>   one needed to run them and the very rich who own these enterprises... And then he
>   is out on the beach under a grey sky, and he comes across one of these
>   rich people, dead, floating along the beach, unattended and maybe
>   representative of the situation that the Earth had come to,
>   technologically advanced, but a dead husk. Beyond those three scenes
>   (England, ship, African Coast), I don't recall anything else.

**Note:** I am confident this is not T. J. Bass's *Half Past Human* or its sequel. I've read those and the social situation is quite different.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this is Earthworks by Brian Aldiss.

I wish I could give lots of supporting quotes but I can't find my copy. However I'm sure I remember the refrigerator sized anti-grav units and the man in the sea. There are various summaries floating around. [Brian Aldiss' site says](http://brianaldiss.co.uk/writing/novels/novels-d-g/earthworks/):

> Out of Africa comes a dead man walking upon the water – a portent of the political adventures into which Knowle Noland, ex-convict, ex-traveller and captain of the 80,000-ton freighter Trieste Star, is about to tumble headlong.
>
> Choked, disease-ridden towns, robots and prison gangs tending the bare, poison drenched countryside are all characteristic of Knowle’s world; only in Africa is the soil still fertile and the people still relatively vital. On the coast of Africa, near Walvis Bay, Knowle runs his freighter aground; and there he meets Justine and the destructive destiny that purges him of guilt and frees him from hallucination.

As I recall the *dead man walking upon the water* is the corpse held up by the anti-gravity pack.

Comment: Much obliged, @JohnRennie. The OP on the other forum never responded, but another poster there (who has read this novel) agreed this was very likely to be the correct match.